# Lead convertion using salesforce mobile app

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, visualforce

I have created one mobile app page salesforce mobilesdk in that when i refresh the page it is not refreshing what is the mistake? the code is below in that i have taken the leads and convert them and i successfully convert them but after converting the lead, that lead again showed in the lead list even i refresh the page also what is the mistake?.

Leads

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
        var client = new remotetk.Client();
        Force.init(null,null,client,null);

        var Leads = new SObjectData();
        Leads.errorHandler = displayError;

        $j(document).ready(function() {
            regBtnClickHandlers();
            getAllLeads();
        });

        function getAllLeads() {
            Leads.fetch('soql','SELECT id, firstName, lastName, company, phone from Lead LIMIT 100',function() {
                showLeads(Leads.data());
            });
        }

        function showLeads(records) {    
            $j('#cList').empty();
            $j.each(Leads.data(),
                function() {
                var newLi = $j('<li></li>');

                var newLink = $j('<a id="' +this.Id+ '" data-transition="flip">' +this.FirstName+ ' '+this.LastName+ '</a>');
                newLink.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $j.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
                    $j('#fName').val(Leads.findRecordById([this.id]).FirstName);
                    $j('#lName').val(Leads.findRecordById([this.id]).LastName);
                    $j('#company').val(Leads.findRecordById([this.id]).Company);
                    $j('#phone').val(Leads.findRecordById([this.id]).Phone);
                    $j('#leadId').val(Leads.findRecordById([this.id]).Id);
                    $j('#error').html('');

                    $j.mobile.changePage('#detailpage', {changeHash: true});
                });
                newLi.append(newLink);            
                newLi.appendTo('#cList');
              //  x++;
              });

            $j.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            $j('#cList').listview('refresh');
        }      

        function addUpdateLead(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var cId = $j('#leadId').val();
            var record = Leads.findRecordById(cId);
            if(record == null) { //new record
                record = Leads.create();
            } 
            record.FirstName = $j('#fName').val();
            record.LastName = $j('#lName').val();
            record.Company = $j('#company').val();
            record.Phone = $j('#phone').val();
            Leads.sync(record,successCallback);
        }

        function deleteLead(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            Leads.remove(Leads.findIndexById($j('#leadId').val()),successCallback);
        }



        //Convert Lead into Account, Contact and Opportunity
    function convertLead(){
        var leadToConvert =  $j('#leadId').val();
        //Invoke JavaScript Remoting function convertLead in Apex controller to convert Lead into Account, Contact and Opportunity
        SalesforceMobileApp.convertLead(leadToConvert,
        //Show the details of new Account created by convet Lead process
        function(result, e){
            $j.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("b", "Converting Lead ...", true);
            $j('#acctName').val(result.Name);
            $j('#acctType').val(result.Type);
            $j('#acctId').val(result.Id);
            $j.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();             
            $j.mobile.changePage('#convertedpage', {changeHash: true});
            getUser(result);
            getContact(result);
            getOpportunity(result);

        });                                                                                                   
    }

    //Get and show the User Name associated with the Account Owner Id
    function getUser(result){
        var acctOwnerId = result.OwnerId;
        //Invoke JavaScript Remoting function getUser in Apex controller to get the User Name associated with the Account Owner Id
        SalesforceMobileApp.getUser(acctOwnerId,
        //Show the User Name associated with the Account Owner Id
        function(result, e){
            $j.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("b", "Converting Lead ...", true);
            $j('#acctOwner').val(result.Name);
            $j.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();             
            $j.mobile.changePage('#convertedpage', {changeHash: true});
        });                                       
    }

    //Get and show the details of new Contact created by convet Lead process
    function getContact(result){
        var newacctId = result.Id;
        //Invoke JavaScript Remoting function getContact in Apex controller to get the details of new Contact created by convet Lead process
        SalesforceMobileApp.getContact(newacctId,
        //Show the details of new Contact created by convet Lead process
        function(result, e){
            $j.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("b", "Converting Lead ...", true);
            $j('#contFirstName').val(result.FirstName);
            $j('#contLastName').val(result.LastName);
            $j('#contTitle').val(result.Title);
            $j('#contPhone').val(result.Phone);
            $j('#contEmail').val(result.Email);
            $j('#contId').val(result.Id);
            $j.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();             
            $j.mobile.changePage('#convertedpage', {changeHash: true});
        });                                       
    }

    //Get and show the details of new Opportunity created by convet Lead process           
    function getOpportunity(result){
        var newacctId = result.Id;
        //Invoke JavaScript Remoting function getOpportunity in Apex controller to get the details of new Opportunity created by convet Lead process
        SalesforceMobileApp.getOpportunity(newacctId,
        //Show the details of new Opportunity created by convet Lead process
        function(result, e){
            $j.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("b", "Converting Lead ...", true);
            $j('#opptyName').val(result.Name);
            $j('#opptyStageName').val(result.StageName);
            $j('#opptyCloseDate').val(result.Close_Date__c);
            $j('#opptyAmount').val(result.Amount);
            $j('#opptyId').val(result.Id);
            $j.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();             
            $j.mobile.changePage('#convertedpage', {changeHash: true});
        });                                       
    }



        function refreshThePage(){

        $.mobile.loadPage("/apex/new");
    }


        function successCallback(r){
            getAllLeads();
            $j.mobile.changePage('#listpage', {changeHash: true});
        }

        function displayError(e){
            console.log(e);
            $j('#error').html(e[0].message);
        }

        function regBtnClickHandlers() {
            $j('#add').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $j.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
                $j('#fName').val('');
                $j('#lName').val('');
                $j('#company').val('');
                $j('#phone').val('');
                $j('#error').html('');
                $j('#leadId').val('');
                $j.mobile.changePage('#detailpage', {changeHash: true});
                $j.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();            
            });

            $j('#save').click(function(e) {
               addUpdateLead(e);
            });

            $j('#delete').click(function(e) {
               deleteLead(e);
            });
            $j('#convertlead').click(function(e) {
               convertlead(e);
            });

        }
    </script>    
</head>

<body>    
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="listpage">                
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h2>Leads</h2>
            <a href='#' id="add" class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='add' data-theme="b">Add Lead</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" id="leadList">            
            <ul id="cList" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" data-role="listview" 
                data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="detailpage">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <a href='#listpage' id="back2leadList" class='ui-btn-left' data-icon='arrow-l' data-direction="reverse" data-transition="flip">Back</a>
            <h1>Lead Details</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="fName">First Name:</label>
                <input name="fName" id="fName" />
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="lName">Last Name:</label>
                <input name="lName" id="lName" />
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="company">Company:</label>
                <input name="company" id="company"/>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
                <input name="phone" id="phone"/>
            </div>
            <h2 style="color:red" id="error"></h2><br/>
            <input type="hidden" id="leadId" />
            <button id="save" data-role="button" data-icon="check" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" class="save">Save</button>
            <button id="delete" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-inline="true" class="destroy">Delete</button>
            <a href="#convertedpage" id="convertLead" data-theme="b" data-role="button" data-icon="star" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="flip" class='ui-btn-left' onClick="convertLead();" >Convert Lead</a>
        </div>    
    </div> 



    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="convertedpage">   
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Converted Lead Detail</h1>
        <a href='#listpage' id="back2Home" data-role="button" class='ui-btn-left' data-icon="home" data-transition="slide" onClick="refreshThePage();">Back to Home</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Show detal of new Account created by convert Lead process -->
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star" data-iconpos="left" style="background: #236EBC; color: white;">Account</a>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <table>
            <tr>
            <th>Account Owner</th>
            <td><output name="acctOwner" id="acctOwner"></output></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Account Name</th>
            <td><output name="acctName" id="acctName"></output></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Account Type</th>
            <td><output name="acctType" id="acctType"></output></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <h2 style="color:red" id="error"></h2><br/>
        <input type="hidden" id="acctId" />
    </div>   
    <hr size="2"/>

    <!-- Show detal of new Contact created by convert Lead process -->         
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star" data-iconpos="left" style="background: #236EBC; color: white;">Contact</a>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <table>
            <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <td><output name="contFirstName" id="contFirstName"></output></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <td><output name="contLastName" id="contLastName"></output></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <td><output name="contTitle" id="contTitle"></output></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <td><output name="contPhone" id="contPhone"></output></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Email</th>
            <td><output name="contEmail" id="contEmail"></output></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <h2 style="color:red" id="error"></h2><br/>
        <input type="hidden" id="contId"/>
    </div>   
    <hr size="2"/>

    <!-- Show detal of new Opportunity created by convert Lead process -->   
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star" data-iconpos="left" style="background: #236EBC; color: white;">Opportunity</a>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <table>
            <tr>
            <th>Opportunity Name</th>
            <td><output name="opptyName" id="opptyName"></output></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Opportunity Stage</th>
            <td><output name="opptyStageName" id="opptyStageName"></output></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Opportunity Close Date</th>
            <td><output name="opptyCloseDate" id="opptyCloseDate"></output></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Opportunity Amount</th>
            <td><output name="opptyAmount" id="opptyAmount"></output></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <h2 style="color:red" id="error"></h2><br/>
        <input type="hidden" id="opptyId" />
    </div>           
    <center>
    <a href='#listpage' id="back2Home" data-role="button" class='ui-btn-left' data-icon="home" data-transition="slide" onClick="refreshThePage();">Back to Home</a>
    </center>
</div> 




</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In getAllLeads you are not filtering out converted leads in your query, add `where isConverted=false` to the SOQL query.